# auto refresh eclipse view

Tags: eclipse, plugins

i have created a sample view in eclipse using the following code.i want the view to be 
automatically refereshed.the part of code in quotes "" gives refresh option but it is done 
manually.can anyone help me know how it can be done automatically

```
public class SampleView extends ViewPart {


    public static final String ID = "tab.views.SampleView";


    private TableViewer viewer;



    class ViewContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {
        public void inputChanged(Viewer v, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        }
        public void dispose() {
        }
        public Object[] getElements(Object parent) {
            return new String[] { "Status of your hudson build  is:  "  +hudson.d};
        }

    }
    class ViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider {
        public String getColumnText(Object obj, int index) {
            return getText(obj);
        }
        public Image getColumnImage(Object obj, int index) {
            return getImage(obj);
        }
        public Image getImage(Object obj) {
            return PlatformUI.getWorkbench().
                    getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_ADD);

        }


    }



    public SampleView() {
    }



    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
        viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());

        viewer.setInput(getViewSite());



        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(viewer.getControl(), "Tab.viewer");

        hookContextMenu();

    }
    " private void hookContextMenu() {
         MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");
          Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());
          viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
          Action refresh =new Action() {
                    public void run() {
                        // initialize();
                         viewer.refresh();

                    }
          };
          refresh.setText("Refresh");
          menuMgr.add(refresh);
 }"



    public void setFocus() {
        viewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to refresh the tree contents automatically, if you fill it using JFace Data Binding, that would not work with remote build results.

I recommend either using a model with notification support: when the model changes, its listeners are notified. Then your view could listen for these notifications and refresh itself.

If for some reason this is not possible, you have to poll your models manually. For that I recommend creating a Job that is executed in the background automatically (its last step is to reschedule itself some times later), that checks whether the model changed and refreshes the view.